# Protractor blur test fails (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, webkit, protractor

I am having a problem with protractor when I try to run a test for a click event that blurs a background image.

The test code:

```
describe('homepage background', function(){

  it('should blur on click', function(){
    var searchBox = element(by.id("inputAnimation"));

    searchBox.click().then(function(){
      var background = element(by.id("carousel-background"));
      expect(background.getCssValue('-webkit-filter')).toEqual('blur(8px)');
    });
  });

});
```

I get this error:

```
Expected 'blur(16px)' to equal 'blur(8px)'.
```

The css:

```
.header-section {
    .background-container {
        height:inherit; background-color: @darkgray;
        .sp-img-dyn, .sp-img {
            overflow:hidden; width:100%; background-position:center top; background-size:cover;
            &.blurred { overflow:hidden; -webkit-filter:blur(8px); }
        }
        .sp-img-dyn { max-width:1920px; height:100%; margin:0 auto; }
        .sp-img { height: 300px; }
    }
}
```

I checked in Chrome, the computed css says it s `blur(16px)`. I am not sure about the source of this bug. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Update: I just discovered that the test only succeeds if I focus on the chrome window where the tests are performed. It says 16px otherwise. I am not sure about what creates that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait until the value changes:

```
var searchBox = $('#carousel-background');
searchBox.click();
browser.wait(function(){
  return searchBox.getCssValue('-webkit-filter').then(function(filterVal){
    // Wait until this becomes true.
    return filterVal === 'blur(16px)'
  });
});
```

You can debug with `browser.sleep(milliseconds)` after you click to make sure protractor is not picking up the value before it changes.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I just discovered that the test only succeeds if I focus on the chrome window where the tests are performed. It says 16px otherwise. I am not sure about what creates that behaviour.